# Is it necessary to take bath before making wudu?

Tags: wudu

Is it necessary to take bath before making wudu? Is there any authentic hadith? I heard from some people that wudu in in complete without taking bath? Is it True?

Comment: Greater ritual impurity such as from intercourse, ejaculation, menstruation etc. requires a bath and wudu will not suffice. Lesser impurity from urinating, defecating etc. is removed by wudu and does not require a bath. You might have mixed up the question, some people might say that bath is incomplete without wudu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. Wudhu is just the simple washing before prayer, when ghusl is not necessary. Why to bath before wudhu, when it is not commanded? As a Muslim you have to live ecologically too and save water. Do not invent new steps into the steps of wudhu. The procedure of wudhu is clearly defined.

Not even in the big washing, in ghusl, you perform double washing. Wudhu is included in ghusl. Ghusl is a higher worth than wudhu. Ghusl replaces wudhu. But what you can do, if you can afford that, is to do ghusl before every prayer. That's possible, but don't add things into it. That will end up in biddah.. Innovation.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not necessary to make ghusl. Rather, it is necessary and obligatory to make wudu before prayer. Because Wudu is very important than ghusl. Because God does not accept the prayer of the one who did not made wudu but ghusl. But, if you do ghusl you must have intention to do wudu, but if you do not do wudoo, that is not sufficient with no need of wudoo.

And God knows best.

---

Link sources:

1) https://islamqa.info/en/99543